# Hamiltonian matrix representation vs. operator representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

I have a general question about second quantization and its relation to the matrix representation of operators in the first-quantized language. Specifically, I am a bit confused about how to convert between the matrix representation of a Hamiltonian and its operator form.

For example, if I have the Hamiltonian:
$$H = \sum_m (C_1 a^\dagger_m a_{m+1} + C_2 a^\dagger_{m+1} a_m)$$
how would I write this in matrix form? Does $a^\dagger_m$ correspond to row $m$ or column $m$ of the matrix?

Also, when using $| \psi \rangle = \sum_m v_m a_m^\dagger |0 \rangle $, how should I write the Schrodinger equation $i (d/dt) |\psi \rangle = H |\psi \rangle$ in matrix-vector form? I understand that $| \psi \rangle $ would be a column vector.

And if I have an on-site energy term on the LHS of the Schrodinger equation (for example, $i (d/dt) |\psi \rangle + \epsilon |\psi \rangle$, why does this appear as a $a^\dagger_{m} a_m$ term in the Hamiltonian?

Could someone also point me to a good reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the particle occupation basis $\{ n_m\}$ where $n_m$ is an eigenvalue of $a^{\dagger}_m a^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_m$. Also, we need $C^*_1 = C^{\vphantom{*}}_2$ for Hermiticity. Anyway, you can write
$$ H = \sum_{\{n_m\}} \, \sum_{j=1}^N \,\left( C \, \left|n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_j+1,n_{j+1}-1,\cdots,n_N\middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm}\middle\langle  n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_j,n_{j+1},\cdots,n_N\right| + \mathit{h.c.} \right)$$
in Dirac's Bra-Ket notation, where I used $j$ instead of $m$ to label sites. Basically $a^{\dagger}_m$ maps the state with $n_m$ particles on the $m$th site to the state with $n_m+1$ particles on that site. **It corresponds to neither row $m$ nor column $m$**, since the matrix is $M^N \times M^N$, where $M$ is the maximum number of particles on each site and $N$ is the total number of sites!

Anyway, the operator notation conveys precisely the same information much more compactly in what's called the "second quantized" formulation of quantum mechanics.

To write the time-dependent Schrödinger equation in this form, you just make all the coefficients of the state you act on time dependent. Then you just say that the time derivative of these coefficients is proportional to a linear combination of all coefficients at that time. But this is not the way you *solve* the time-dependent Schrödinger equation.

The way you do that is by diagonalizing $H$ (which is easiest in the operator basis, using a Fourier transform in the translation-invariant example you included). This is the same as solving the time-independent Schrödinger equation first. The result is
$$ H = \sum_k \, \varepsilon_k \, a^{\dagger}_k a^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_k = \sum_{\{n_k\}} \, \left( \sum_k  \varepsilon_k \, n_k \right)  \left| \{n_k\} \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \middle\langle \{n_k \} \right| $$
where the parenthetical term above is the many-body energy $E(\{n_k\})$, where $\{n_k\}$ are the occupancies of the energy eigenmodes, parameterized by the momenta $k$. Exponentiating the matrix above is equivalent to expontiating the part in parantheses, so that
$$ U (t) = \exp (- {\rm i} H t) = \sum_{\{n_k\}} \, \exp \left( - {\rm i} \, t \sum_k  \varepsilon_k \, n_k \right)  \left| \{n_k\} \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \middle\langle \{n_k \} \right| $$
and you just apply this operator to the initial state (as a column vector) to get the time-evolved state.

An on-site energy term should be something that is a function of the occupancy $n_m$ of site $m$. And $n_m$ is an eigenvalue of $a^{\dagger}_m a^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_m$. If that term is like a chemical potential, then it is proportional to the number of particles, and that's why $a^{\dagger}_m a^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_m$ shows up. Because it counts the number of particles. But this term is part of your Hamiltonian, and an on-site energy term could be any function of the number of particles on the site $m$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Do you have a good reference for this?

Comment: This is just second quantization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization so some QM texts will do it (I assume Sakurai), and many-body texts (e.g., by Mahan, Piers Coleman, Ziman, and others) and condensed-matter texts (e.g., Ashcroft and Mermin, S. Simon, Altland and Simons, X.-G. Wen). The boson case is the same as the SHO.